# Unwind segue is dismissing two view controllers when the presenting view controller is a child of tabbarController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift5

Unwind segue dismissing two view controllers when the presenting view controller is a UIViewController presented by a child of tabbarController.
Here's the structure:

```
tabBarController (root) -> child(first tab) -> MiddleViewController -> TopViewController
```

When I perform segue(unwind) from TopViewController, it gets dismissed and dismisses the MiddleViewController. Would it be because the presentingViewController of middleViewController is a child of the tabBarController? The function with segue parameter is indeed inside MiddleViewController. What would be the problem?

The TopViewController presentation style is  `.OverCurrentContext`

Comment: Unclear. If MiddleViewController is a child of the tab bar controller, it cannot be “dismissed”, because it was never presented. What actually happens? Is it that everything goes black? If so did you switch to a different tab and come back? If so that is a well known bug; you must not let the user switch tabs while a tab is presenting another view controller.

Comment: Actually, a child from tabbarController presented the MiddleViewController. When the unwind segue is performed from topViewController, the top and middle ViewController both get dismissed and I get back to the first tab again.

Comment: Then you've hooked up the unwind segue incorrectly. If you do it right, you go back to where you want to go back to. The middle view controller is not dismissed automatically.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm seeing the same behavior and thinking it's a bug in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You've hooked up the unwind segues incorrectly. If you hook them up correctly, you go back to the middle view controller without dismissing it (until you ask to dismiss it).

As you can see here, we go First -> Middle -> Top and then Top -> Middle -> First in good order, one at a time.

[image]

Comment: I am manually  doing the unwind segue using `performSegue(withIdentifier:, sender:)` not using a UIButton to unwind.